# Orden y formas de agrupar elementos en listas enlazadas

Tags: java, lista, ordenamiento

Buenas, alquien puede ayudarme con este problema? Me gustaría entender completamente el manejo de las listas enlazadas y me quedé con este ejemplo.
Realizar una aplicación que permita generar distintos listados relativos a una determinada comunidad de vecinos. 
Para ello necesitaremos almacenar los datos de los distintos vecinos: nombre, apellidos, bloque, puerta, cuota mensual 
y el importe total que debe a la comunidad.
La aplicación permitirá realizar los siguientes listados:
 - Listado ordenado alfabéticamente de todos los vecinos de la comunidad.
 - Listado de los vecinos ordenados decrecientemente por importe que deben.
 - Listado de los vecinos pertenecientes a un determinado bloque.
 - Listado de vecinos ordenados por el importe de la cuota mensual que deben pagar.

Tengo hecho el primer apartado pero no sé si estoy haciéndolo de la manera correcta. Agradezco la ayuda.

Vecino.java

```
public class Vecino implements Comparable <Vecino> {
    private String nombre;
    private String apellidos;
    private int bloque;
    private char puerta;
    private double cuotaMensual;
    private double importeDebe;

    Vecino(String nombre, String apellidos, int bloque, char puerta, double cuotaMensual, double importeDebe){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
        this.bloque = bloque;
        this.puerta = puerta;
        this.cuotaMensual = cuotaMensual;
        this.importeDebe = importeDebe;
    }

    Vecino(){

    }

    /**
     * @return the nombre
     */
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    /**
     * @param nombre the nombre to set
     */
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    /**
     * @return the apellidos
     */
    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }

    /**
     * @param apellidos the apellidos to set
     */
    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    /**
     * @return the bloque
     */
    public int getBloque() {
        return bloque;
    }

    /**
     * @param bloque the bloque to set
     */
    public void setBloque(int bloque) {
        this.bloque = bloque;
    }

    /**
     * @return the puerta
     */
    public char getPuerta() {
        return puerta;
    }

    /**
     * @param puerta the puerta to set
     */
    public void setPuerta(char puerta) {
        this.puerta = puerta;
    }

    /**
     * @return the cuotaMensual
     */
    public double getCuotaMensual() {
        return cuotaMensual;
    }

    /**
     * @param cuotaMensual the cuotaMensual to set
     */
    public void setCuotaMensual(double cuotaMensual) {
        this.cuotaMensual = cuotaMensual;
    }

    /**
     * @return the importeDebe
     */
    public double getImporteDebe() {
        return importeDebe;
    }

    /**
     * @param importeDebe the importeDebe to set
     */
    public void setImporteDebe(double importeDebe) {
        this.importeDebe = importeDebe;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Vecino o) {
        return this.nombre.compareTo(o.getNombre()); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {

    LinkedList<Vecino> vecinos = new LinkedList<>();

    public void mostrarTodosVecinos(LinkedList<Vecino> vecinos){
        System.out.println("Listado de vecinos ordenados alfabéticamente: ");

        Collections.sort(vecinos);

            for (Vecino vecino : vecinos) {
                System.out.println("Nombre: "+vecino.getNombre()+" "+vecino.getApellidos()+"\n"+
                                    "Bloque: "+vecino.getBloque()+"\n"+
                                    "Puerta: "+vecino.getPuerta()+"\n"+
                                    "Cuota mensual: "+vecino.getCuotaMensual()+"\n"+
                                    "Importe que debe: "+vecino.getImporteDebe()+"\n");
            }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main prueba = new Main();
        LinkedList<Vecino> vecinos = new LinkedList<>();
        Vecino veci = new Vecino("Jaime","Weirk",2,'A',20,40);
        Vecino veci1 = new Vecino("Laura","Gil",1,'C',20,20);
        Vecino veci2 = new Vecino("Mike","Aton",4,'B',20,60);
        Vecino veci3 = new Vecino("Billy","Willy",5,'D',20,10);
        vecinos.add(veci);
        vecinos.add(veci1);
        vecinos.add(veci2);
        vecinos.add(veci3);
        prueba.mostrarTodosVecinos(vecinos);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ordenar , el método que realizas es una opción válida y correcta ... pero quisiera proponerte otra opción que son el uso de [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) , para esto hay que crear el método `toString()` en tu clase Vecino (Puede modificarlo y darle formato que usted desee)

```
public String toString() {
    return "Vecino{" + "nombre=" + nombre + ", apellidos=" + apellidos + ", bloque=" + bloque + ", puerta=" + puerta + ", cuotaMensual=" + cuotaMensual + ", importeDebe=" + importeDebe + '}'+ "\n";
}
```

Para hacer el ordenamiento y  agrupamiento, quedaría así el código

```
LinkedList<Vecino> vecinos = new LinkedList<>();
 ......

    /* Ordenados por Nombre */
    vecinos.sort((p1,p2) -> p1.getNombre().compareTo(p2.getNombre()));
    vecinos.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.toString()));

    /* Ordenados Importe Debe */
    System.out.println("");
    vecinos.sort((p1,p2) -> Double.valueOf(p2.getImporteDebe()).compareTo(p1.getImporteDebe()));
    vecinos.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.toString()));

    /* Ordenados Importe Mensual */
    System.out.println("");
    vecinos.sort((p1,p2) -> Double.valueOf(p2.getCuotaMensual()).compareTo(p1.getCuotaMensual()));
    vecinos.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.toString()));

    /* Por Grupos */

     vecinos.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(foo -> foo.getBloque(),Collectors.toList()))
    .forEach((id,lista)->
            System.out.println("Grupo " +id+ "\n"+ lista.toString()));
```

> Como observación , a menos que sea uso exclusivo es mejor usar `ArrayList` en lugar de `LinkedList` , para mejor referencia leer esta pregunta en inglés pero muy interesante 
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist

Comment: Gracias @Dev. Joel , ahora entiendo un poco mejor el funcionamiento de ambas estructuras, era la solución que buscaba y le agradezco su ayuda y tiempo. Saludos.